# Replacing the character in the string

Tags: string, shell, replace, character

I need shell script statements to replace `"*"` sign with the `".*"` in the string. For example: `string1="abc*def"` convert to this `string2:"abc.*def"`. I am trying with this piece of code but it gives wrong output:

```
IN="abc*def"
chr=".*"
arr=$(echo ${args[@]} | tr "*" "\n")
for x in $arr
do
echo -n $x
echo -n ".*"
done

for abc*def   gives abc.*def.* not correct
for abc*def*  gives abc.*def.* correct
for *abc*def* gives abc.*def.* not correct
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
p='*abc*def*'
echo "$p" | sed 's/\*/.*/g'
.*abc.*def.*
```

Make sure you are using correct quoting to avoid shell expanding `*`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ->

```
a='abc*def'
b=.
c="${a/'*'/$b}"
```